# Laravel 5.7 accessor that essentially checks the relativity to the auth user based on a few possible matches

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I have some scopes on my model for `relativeTo` or `notRelativeTo`:

```
public function scopeRelativeTo($query, User $user)
{
    $teamIDs = $user->teams->pluck('id');

    $query->where('assigned_user_id', $user->id)
        ->orWhere('reported_by', $user->id)
        ->orWhereIn('assigned_team_id', $teamIDs);
}


public function scopeNotRelativeTo($query, User $user)
{
    $teamIDs = $user->teams->pluck('id');

    $query->where('assigned_user_id', '!=', $user->id)
        ->orWhere('reported_by', '!=', $user->id)
        ->orWhereNotIn('assigned_team_id', $teamIDs);
}
```

These help build a query based on a possible matches that essentially boil down whether a user has relativity to the object or not. These are great for querying, but I'm also trying to create an accessor on the model that will return a boolean so each object will dynamically know it's relativity to the authenticated user. Fine idea, but not sure where to even start.

```
public function getRelativityAttribute($value)
{
    $user = User::find(auth('api')->user()->id);
}
```

With the authenticated user, and knowing that I also have access to the actual class: `$this`, how might I check the relativity based on those same checks in the scopes and return a boolean value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function getRelativityAttribute($value)
{
    $user = auth('api')->user();
    if (!$user) {
        return false;
    }

    $userId = $user->getKey();
    return $this->assigned_user_id == $userId || $this->reported_by == $userId
           || $user->teams()->where('id', $this->assigned_team_id)->exists();
}
```

Comment: That seems to be returning true for everything, despite the fact that there are clear instances where it shouldn't be.

Comment: I've updated my answer, the last condition should be without the `!`